# How to Convert Some unicode-bidi?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textBox and I want when I write into that textBox (mix language [Persian, English]) the words to be typed into that textbox in the same way as I typed.

```
We/میلاد@12
```

This is the example:

1. we
2. @
3. میلاد
4. /
5. 123

I find this code for css, this code fixed my problem in html, but I need this on WinForm

```
input, textarea { 
     unicode-bidi:bidi-override; 
     direction: RTL; 
}
```

Comment: @John I already told you, i find this code for css and i want to find the way to use that code in c#

Comment: Please ensure you tag your question correctly. Between the title, content, and tags, it was a little confusing to say the least.

Comment: The exact equivalent is the control's RightToLeft property.  Mixing characters from a Latin alphabet, Farsi, arabic digits and punctuation and hoping that the text render engine can sort out the jumble is not terribly realistic.  Explicit [marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text#Marks) are likely needed.